# findOneAndUpdate isn't updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a product, where I need to update the quantity of the product. While using findOneAndUpdate the request is successful but the data isn't changing in the db.

Code:

```
exports.updateQuantity = (req, res) => {
  Item.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.id }, //condition
    { quantity: 2 }, //update
    { new: true },
    function (err, product) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(error);
      } else {
        res.status(201).json("product updated");
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Route :

```
router.post("/updateQuantity", updateQuantity);
```

I also tried giving `{$set :{ quantity: 2 }}` also, but doesn't seems to update.
Also tried switching to put instead of post. But no hope.

Comment: There must be no matching products

Comment: try wrapping your function with `async` and put await before query `await Item.findOneAndUpdate(`

Comment: @AlexBlex The id does exists. I did copy the id after creating the product and also crosschecked in the db.

Comment: Are the _id in the database and in req.body.id of the same type? The former by default is an ObjectId, and the later is a string unless you monkey-patch the request parameters.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yep, the issue was that my my obj has another array within which has same type _id (diff value)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the provided Id exists first before updating like this

```js
exports.updateQuantity = async (req, res) => {
   try{
      let item = await Item.findById(req.body.id)
      if(!item) return res.status(404).json("No product found with the given Id")
      await Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.id,
        { quantity: 2 },
        { new: true },
      );
    }
    catch(ex){
      return res.status(400).send(ex.message)
    }
  
};
```

Comment: The id does exists. I did copy the id after creating the product and also crosschecked in the db.

Comment: And the error is still there?

Comment: Dear @NkubitoPacis, welcome to Stackoverflow. We really appreciate your effort to contribute and help fellow coders. It would be advisable to check your code before posting. It's a professional community and it's not uncommon for wrong and misleading answers to be downvoted.  `Item.findById(req.body.id)` returns an instance of a Query object, not the item from the database as your code snippet implies. Please read the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById .

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the codes

Comment: =) good step in the right direction. Still won't work, but you are close.  Let me say it again: `Item.findById(req.body.id)` returns an instance of a **Query** object, not a Promise. `await` alone won't help.

Comment: I added async to the function which makes the whole function to be called asynchronously and then await awaits that given process then returns the data. You should consider running my codes first.

Comment: yep, as I said the direction is correct - adding async is the right thing to do if you are using await inside. The problem is `Item.findById(req.body.id)` returns the Query object synchronously. There is nothing to await there. Did you run the code? Did you manage to receive "No product found with the given Id" response ever?  Javascript is a tricky language. Your code won't throw any error, it just won't do what you expect.

Comment: Yes i run the code at it executed perfectly. Maybe you can try to run it also

Comment: I find it hard to believe tbh. could you provide full code to reproduce? Stackoverflow is not quite suitable for multi-file examples but if could share it somewhere on github it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. You can find the codes at: https://github.com/N-Pacis/stack-overflow-question-70620425 any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Thanks a mill! You opened my eyes. I indeed missed how they added `Symbol.asyncIterator` to the Query which made this syntax possible. Apologies for my doubts.

Comment: You are welcome. If possible you can again revote my solution